# Django field name starting with a number

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if it's possible to name a field starting with a number:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    ...
    24h_volume = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

That's not possible since Django is built off of Python, and Python does not allow the names of variables (including class attributes) to begin with a number.

You'll have more luck renaming your field to a format that has a prepended name such as "volume_" - for e.g.:

`volume_24h`

Or something along those lines.